# UICollectionView change frame size for iphone

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, cell

How can I change the `UICollectionView` layout size from the code (width and height) ? 
(Not the cell size).
This image here is used to adjust height and width :

[image]

Need some clearance on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

refer to the delegate the of

```
Getting the Size of Items
[– collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:][1]
Getting the Section Spacing
– collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:
– collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
– collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
Getting the Header and Footer Sizes
– collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:
– collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection:
```